# How to fit as many elements as possible into div and move the rest elements to another screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an array of objects, each representing an element I want to display in a slider. Each slide in the slider has a fixed height of 1000px. For example, let's assume I have 10 elements.

My idea is to calculate the height of these 10 elements within the container. This would result in an array of heights, e.g., [300px, 500px, 245px, etc]. Based on these heights, I want to split the elements into chunks. Each chunk will represent a slide that fits within the height of the container.

Here's how I'm planning to add elements:

Start by creating an empty array to hold the chunks, and another one for the elements of the first slide.
For each element, check if its height can fit in the remaining space of the current slide.

- For example, if I have 1000px available and the first element is 300px, it fits, so I push this element to the first slide. This leaves 700px of space.
- Then, I check the next element. If it's 500px, it also fits in the remaining space, so I push it to the first slide. Now, I'm left with 200px of space.
- If the next element is 245px, it doesn't fit into the remaining space. Therefore, I move this element to the next slide.

However, I'm running into a problem: I can't retrieve the heights of the elements. To get the height of the elements using useRef, I first need to render them on the screen. This isn't ideal, as I want to immediately display them correctly. The issue is essentially that I can't determine how to split the elements into slides until I know their heights, but I can't know their heights until I've rendered them.

How I solved it is to just give each element static height of, for example, 300px and then just divide the container height by 300 and I get how many item can I fit into the container but this approach is bad.

Here I drew page with 3 slides for better understanding how it should work.

[image]